# Can I use PhantomJS with Cucumber-js

Tags: cucumber, phantomjs, zombie.js

I've been using Zombie.js with my cucumber-js scripts but having a bit of trouble and can't get my issues resolved as of yet. It's extremely late in my game to switch to a different headless browser, but, if I can't solve my issues in zombie, I might need to make the jump.

However, I can't seem to figure out if I can integrate it into my cucumber-js scripts the way I integrated zombie.  PhantomJS seems to be a standalone thing, but I need it to run as a required module.

I've scanned the documentation and can't figure out if I can do this.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you had any progress with this? Looking into this as well

Comment: This might help https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/08/cucumber-capybara-poltergeist/

Comment: I really like zombie with cucumber-js! Maybe we can help you with your zombie issues here. https://github.com/webforge-labs/cuked-zombie

Answer (score 1):

Yes. We created an open source package that allows you to do exactly this, it runs Phantom in GhostDriver mode so it runs without selenium.

https://github.com/xolvio/chimp

You also get synchronous javascript for Webdriver (no callbacks, no promises) ;)